# Proving an inequality involving factorials

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

In some certain exercise I am asked to show that $\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N},\frac{n^k}{k^k} \leq 
{n\choose k}$.
I have bounded the left side by $\frac{n^k}{k^k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$. When I computed in Sage for an specific $k$ both discrete graphs of $\frac{n^k}{k!}$ and ${n \choose k}$, I obtained that this inequality was true. However, obviously that is not enought. I was wondering if someone could give just a hint, not the complete proof but just the way to go through.

Comment: Just show that $\frac{n}{k} \le \frac{n-i}{k-i}$ for all $n,k,i$ with $n\ge k>i \ge 0$. You can then prove the original statement by applying this to each of the $k$ factors.

Comment: Note that the original inequality isn't true for $ n < k$, so it doesn't hold $ \forall n, k$.

Comment: In my exercise that detail is not indicated, but I thought it only would make sense taking that into account. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint for solving the exercise: Write out the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$, and reduce so that you have $k$ terms in the numerator and $k$ terms in the denominator. Split this into a product of $k$ fractions and compare it to $\frac{n^k}{k^k}=\frac{n}{k}\cdot \frac{n}{k} \cdots \frac{n}{k}$ ($k$ times). Write me a comment if you need further hints.